# How is the linked question off-topic?

Tags: support

I just watched [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345985/help-ran-sudo-apt-get-f-install-and-it-removed-almost-everything-including-e) question get closed as off-topic. The question involves reinstalling / recovering accidentally deleted packages in Ubuntu.

Granted, it is an older version (16.04), but I was under the impression that all Ubuntu versions were within the scope of Ask Ubuntu. Am I wrong about that or overlooking another detail?

I can see it needs improving. OP left out a few major details, such as which packages are missing. I am sure that it has duplicates under different contexts, but as you know, with Linux systems, what works in one instance may or may not work in the next.

Regardless, I don't understand how it is off-topic.

Comment: No, only actively maintained Ubuntu versions are in scope here. Versions that have reached end of life are explicitly off topic. See the last bullet point in "Questions you should avoid" here: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1345985/revisions) or the [first version of the post](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1345985/1), which has

> Linux Distro: Elementary OS Loki

That's not an official flavor.

Here is the close reason text which, due to a terrible bug, is currently only shown to high rep users and the OP (sorry to everyone for the confusion this causes):

> **This is not about an [official Ubuntu flavor](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)**. Questions about other Linux distributions can be asked on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), those about Windows on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), those about Apple products on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and generic programming questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

There's also the [elementary OS Stack Exchange](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/).

That's why I closed the question (but it's not deleted).

The OP subsequently edited the question and removed the OS information, which is not a good idea since we don't know exactly how elementary OS differs from Ubuntu.

Comment: You might also want to mention that no, not all Ubuntu versions are on topic.